# Attacking city with Encampment district

Tags: civilization-6

I am attacking a city that has an encampment.

Should I attack the encampment first? The AI does not have any units around at the moment.

What are the pros and cons if there is an encampment district while I am attacking a city? What could the encampment do to hamper my assault?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The encampment will bombard you with ranged fire as long as you are in range of it, so unless you're confident you can soak the additional damage it's best to position your siege forces on the other side of the city walls where it can't range on you.

As far as I've been able to tell there's no inherent value in taking out the Encampment first other than "it won't be used against me while I'm besieging the city".

Reduce an encampment's defences and take it like a city. At this point the encampment is now "pillaged".

Comment: Plus you have to repair the district once you capture the city if you damage it. IMO encampments are best left alone unless you HAVE to go through them to get to the city.

Comment: Or if there's an artillery unit fortified in there that's making your life difficult.

Comment: Note also that  for player units may spawn in the encampment/city when produced, depending on which has free slot. Possibly if you leave encampment behind you, it may spawn unit that attacks your army from behind.